# ServiceStack client send OPTION instead of Get or post

Tags: cors, servicestack

I am trying to configure servicestack CorsPlugin with typescript JsonServiceClient.
Client side code looks like:

```js
        const client = new JsonServiceClient( 'http://localhost:5000' );
        client.password = 'password';
        client.userName = 'username';
        client.get( new Authenticate() ).then( (authRes) => {
            console.log( authRes );
            let req = new CreateAccount();
            client.bearerToken = authRes.bearerToken;
            req.mail = 'demo';
            client.post( req ).then( (res) => {
                console.log( res );
            } );
        } );
```

```js
            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
                allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization",
                allowCredentials: true,
                allowOriginWhitelist: new[]
                    {"http://localhost:3000", "https://www.app.production.com"}));
```

when the client sends requests it suppose to be GET but in the console it shows like OPTIONS and data are actually received. So it kind of run but does not make proper http verbs. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you make a [CORS Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), the browser automatically sends a preflight OPTIONS request to determine whether the Server approves the COR request from the origin website.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I know about preflight OPTIONS but after preflight supposed to be regular get or post which never happens in chrome. I found that it is issue only on chrome. In firefox all is how it should be.

Comment: @Roman That usually indicates that the CORS request was denied. Does Chrome write any errors to the Console?

Comment: no it does not. What is really interesting that OPTIONS returns value from api point.

Comment: @Roman Can update your question to include the Raw HTTP Request/Response Headers of the OPTIONS request.